# Gtk 3.0 windows with treeview inside expander

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

In python, with Gtk 3.0, I try to obtain a windows with a notebook. Inside this notebook, some expander. Each expander would contain a treeview.

After some search, I have this code :

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        # Create liststore which will be contained within treeview
        # liststore has 3 rows and 3 columns
        self.store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, float)
        self.store.append(["string1.1", "string1.2", 1.0])
        self.store.append(["string2.1", "string2.2", 2.0])
        self.store.append(["string3.1", "string3.2", 3.0])

        # Create treeview which will be contained within one expander
        # treeview has 3 columns and contain liststore
        self.tree = Gtk.TreeView(self.store)
        for i, column_title in enumerate(["col1", "col2", "col3"]):
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
            self.tree.append_column(column)

        # Addind a callback to selection_changed event of treeview
        select = self.tree.get_selection()
        select.connect("changed", self.on_tree_selection_changed)

        # Create expander which will be contained within one notebook page
        # Adding treeview inside expander
        self.page1 = Gtk.Expander()
        self.page1.set_border_width(10)
        self.page1.add(self.tree)

        # Create notebook and adding expander inside first page
        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.add(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label('Page1'))

        self.Window = Gtk.Window()
        self.Window.add(self.notebook)

        self.show_all()

    def on_tree_selection_changed(self, selection):
        model, treeiter = selection.get_selected()
        if treeiter != None:
          print("You selected", model[treeiter][0])

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I don't manage to display treeview inside expander.
But without expander, treeview is displayed.

I work on ubuntun 12.04 and launch my programm with `python ihm.py` command.

Some people can explain me why it don't work?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the notebook to a parent two times. Remove the line

```
self.Window.add(self.notebook)
```

This worked for me. It is strange that you don't get an error message about this.

Comment: Many thanks. Effectively, it suppress the warning message at execution. But does not allow my program to run (expander is always empty).

Comment: There is something strange going on. I just checked again and it works for me.

Comment: I made a mistake. I work on Ubuntu 12.04. But tell me if I wrong, since we use the same version of gtk, it does not matter ?

Comment: I use Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04). This means we are using a different version of Gtk. Sometimes the API changes, but that should create an error message. Do you have an error or anything? I have no error at all.

Comment: I have no error since I remove `code`self.Window.add(self.notebook)`code`.

Comment: You could try a newer version of Linux. Some old versions of Ubuntu had problems with Gtk, but it does not really seem like that is your problem because the window does show up. Sorry I cannot help you more.